# Proper Node.js API for determining whether or not `100 Continue` was sent

Tags: node.js, express

I have a strange edge case of HTTP and HTTP-like handling where I have to support some broken clients.  Specifically, a client will make an HTTP PUT request, and I need to send a `200 OK` after the request headers are received, before the client sends its request body.  Normally, I do this:

```
app.put('/*', function (req, res, next) {
  res.socket.write('HTTP/1.0 200 OK\r\n\r\n');
  /* Pipe socket and handle data here */
}
```

However, with newer versions of Node.js (v6.2.2 as of this writing), when a client connects with a proper HTTP/1.1 request and `Expect: 100-continue` in its request headers, the HTTP server will (correctly) send an `HTTP/1.1 100 Continue` message, immediately before I get a chance to send my own response status line.  As a result, the client would get two status lines:

```
HTTP/1.1 100 Continue
HTTP/1.0 200 OK
```

This isn't a huge problem.  I just need to detect when the Node.js HTTP server took care of the status line, so I don't send a duplicate.  The trick is, I don't think this API is properly exposed.  I prodded around and came up with this method:

```
app.put('/*', function (req, res, next) {
  if (!res._sent100) {
    res.socket.write('HTTP/1.0 200 OK\r\n\r\n');
  }
  /* Pipe socket and handle data here */
}
```

My Question:  Is there a better way to detect when the built-in HTTP server has sent `100 Continue` than by using `res._sent100`?

There is an [HTTP server `checkContinue` event](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_event_checkcontinue).  However, if I handle that event then the normal events don't fire.  I'm using this in conjunction with Express, and I need the normal request events so that the normal middleware stack will run.  If I could handle `checkContinue`, write my own property to `res`, and then pass it back to the normal stack for handling, then all would be well.  But, I don't see a documented way to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
server.on('checkContinue', (req, res) => {
  res.mySent100 = true;
  res.writeContinue();
  server.emit('request', req, res);
});
```

(where `server` is the HTTPServer instance that is serving your Express app)